# Why aren't my Magento pages loading?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am experiencing some problems with Magento, when I load a product sometimes it works and sometimes I get just this:

[image]

The php memory is set to max for the webserver and compilation is enabled I have flushed the cache checked my files etc, I am not sure what the problem is, the page when it loads contains adjustable options powered by javascript, any ideas what this could be ?

Comment: Can you provide the url of the page? When you check your browser console are you seeing any errors reported?

Comment: its not specific to one url it does it with all products, which doesn't help me narrow it down :/, and as you can see from the edited picture there are no erros coming from the page, my theory is that there is too much going on with this page, as with too much javascript or something I could be wrong but.

Comment: Have you tried using the default theme?

Comment: Have you checked the source of the page ? Sometimes PHP errors don't display on the screen, but are present in the source

Comment: No, this is a live site can't be changing the theme now, we are using the same theme for another website and we have had no problems like this with that one.

Comment: If the error is not client side, have you enabled logging and checked your Magento log files for relevant errors?

Comment: Error reporting is enabled but nothing is showing on the report :/

Comment: You might find this useful: Fundamentals of debugging a Magento store: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you have an over-eager 'api' doing things, e.g. a warehouse checking inventory of orders and doing things to process them. What happens is that the indexes get updated, and, whilst this is happening, there effectively is no index. With no index things don't show.

To determine whether this is the case you can try to disable the flat catalog in system config, if problem persists then at least you have determined whether or not it is a problem with indexes.

Note other things could be upsetting the flat tables, if it is not an API thing then check what local modules you have and see if you can find a culprit.

The thing about it returning nothing intermittently (due to indexes) is that there may be no error in any log.

Comment: Flat catalog was set to no :/, it maybe an issue with the theme, but I can think why it's doing it intermittently and the fact it's not specific to one product it's all the products.